# Python unittest's setUpClass does not work

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following code:

```
import unittest

class TestFMP(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        FMP_object = MyClass1(path, {})
        Locator_object = MyClass2(path)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print('YYY')

    def test_method(self):

        self.assertEqual(FMP_object.method1(), Locator_object.method2())
```

My understanding is, that the setUpClass() should be executed once on instantiation of the TestFMP class, and provide constant access to FMP_object and Locator_object. However, when I run the test_method, I get the following error:

```
testcase = TestFMP()
testcase.test_method()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-b11e25b4803c> in <module>
      1 testcase = TestFMP()
----> 2 testcase.test_method()

<ipython-input-276-dba1c1e55b1a> in test_method(self)
     12     def test_method(self):
     13 
---> 14         self.assertEqual(FMP_object.method1(), Locator_object.method2())

NameError: name 'FMP_object' is not defined
```

I get the same result when I attempt to access FMP_object/Locator_object with self. prefix in the test_method().

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

I am getting this on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

`setupClass(cls)` is called, but the results you computed aren't stored. You need to assign the results to an attribute on the `cls` (`TestFMP` class), and not just as variables, then you can retrieve these results through the `self` as `self` can access `cls` attributes (but not the inverse).

Something like the following will achieve what you're after:

```py
import unittest

class TestFMP(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # set `fmp` and `locator` onto the class through `cls` 
        cls.fmp = MyClass1(path, {})
        cls.locator = MyClass2(path)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # Dispose of those resources through `cls.fmp` and `cls.locator`
        print('YYY')

    def test_method(self):
        # access through self: 
        self.assertEqual(self.fmp.method1(), self.locator.method2())
```

Comment: I have done that, but now I am getting the following error: AttributeError: 'TestFMP' object has no attribute 'fmp'.